# VS Code doesn't show any info on Hovering on functions in typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, intellisense

I downloaded a few extensions that deal with function info on Hover, and the latest one I downloaded was Typescript (https://www.typescriptlang.org/). But even this one, doesn't show me the info as it is described on this vs code extension report.
[image]

As you can see in this picture labeled 'IntelliSense', it gives you all the methods' info on a connected window on the right. I don't have that. In order to see the IntelliSense info, I have to click on the word, then press Ctrl + Space. Why is that?

Please Help.

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% sure, but I think that if you have a separate typescript file, that will solve the problem. Whenever I tried to insert my code into  tags, I had the same problem you described. However having a separate file for the (in my case JS) code, made it work.